# Mal posicionamiento de un menu al contraer explorador ¿Podrían ayudarme?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Estoy tomando un curso  donde  se  ocupa B3 (Bootstrap 3) y al momento  de encoger el  explorador la  parte de My Account se posiciona en la parte de abajo
como podrán  ver en la  imagen:

[image: Pagina web responsiva]

La verdad he  checado mil veces el  código (el  que aparece a continuación). también lo he comparado con el  código original incluyendo su  CSS y está igual
¿Alguien tiene un buen ojo que me ayude a identificar el error o en  este caso podría ayudarme a resolverlo?

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">

            <div class="container">
            <!---->
                <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            <!--Logo--->
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="YourLogo"></a><!--End Logo-->

            <div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Photos<strong class="caret"></strong></a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Nature</a></li><!--End Nature-->
                            <li><a href="#">My Dog</a></li><!--End MyDog-->
                            <li><a href="#">Sunsets</a></li><!--End Sunsets-->
                            <li class="divider"></li><!--End divider-->
                            <li class="dropdown-header">More Photos </li><!--End Dropdown-Header -->
                            <li><a href="#">Things</a></li>
                        </ul><!--End Dropdown-menu-->
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
                </ul><!--End Navbar-->

                <form class="navbar-form pull-left">
                        <input type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="Search This" id="searchInput">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                        </button><!--End Button-->      </form><!--End navbar-form-->

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> My Account<strong class="caret"></strong></a><!--End My Account-->

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span> Settings</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> Update Profile</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider">
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Sign Out</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul><!--End dropdownMenu (My Account)-->
                    </li><!--End dropdown-->
                </ul><!--End Pull-Right-->
            </div><!--End Nav-Collapse-->

        </div><!--End Container-->  
    </div><!--End Navbar-->
```

CSS:

```
#searchInput{
width:200px;
}
.navbar-brand{
   padding:13px 15px;
 }
```

Comment: uno de los errores es que no es `nav-collapse`, sino `navbar-collapse`, se te ha colado la palabra nav a secas :)

Comment: qué versión de jquery estás usando? el plugin para colapsar el navbar no funciona en jQuery 1.x

Comment: esta versión  del  Jquery:jquery-1.8.2.min.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te traigo un ejemplo de lo que pides: (para probarlo, mejor que lo copies y lo pruebes por codepen, por ejemplo) Aquí se ve solo la opción colapsada, ya que el visor es muy pequeño:

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Collection of nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Messages <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Inbox</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Drafts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sent Items</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Trash</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </form>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Gracias :D muuchas gracias :3